# How to fix "can't assign to operator" error in python

Tags: python

I am trying to put an exponent in my code and for some reason it keeps giving me a "can't assign operator" error for it and I'm not sure why.

I changed to code to not have any 'int' and I tried importing math because I wasn't sure if exponents needed to be imported, clearly neither worked. Other than these, I'm not sure what is wrong with the code.

```py
name = input("Enter name: ")

bank_name = input("Enter bank name: ")

initial_investment = input("Enter initial investment amount: ")

annual_interest_rate = input("Enter annual interest rate: ")

investment_years = input("Enter number of years to invest money: ")

investment_months = investment_years * 12

monthly_interest_rate = ((int(annual_interest_rate) / 12) / 100)

MIR^IM = (1 + int(monthly_interest_rate)) ** (int(investment_months))

final = int(initial_investment) * int(MIR^IM)

gain = int(final) - int(initial_investment)
```

I wanted to MIR^IM variable to produce (1 + monthly interest rate) ^ investment months

Comment: Format your code with `{}` button

Comment: This is because of `^`. You are trying to assign to expression `MIR ^ IM`. Change name of the variable to `MIR_IM`. Note: `^` doesn't stand for power.

Comment: Can you share the Traceback?

Comment: @bubble thanks I appreciate it that worked and yeah i learned that about 20 minutes ago. Just started like a week ago at most.

Comment: @Carter I have no idea what that is or how to get it, but if you'd let me know I'd appreciate it. Also, someone already answered my question, but I'd still like to know what a traceback is and how to share it.

Comment: use these guidelines to write code [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: A "traceback" is the full text of the error you get. If you simply copy-paste that information to your question, it would be easier for others to find answers for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have an operator as a variable name. In your case `^` (XOR) is the operator causing the issue.

> XOR Sets each bit to 1 if only one of two bits is 1

Just change your variable name from MIR^IM to something like:

```
MIR_IM = (1 + int(monthly_interest_rate)) ** (int(investment_months))
```

Answer (score 0):

"MIR^IM" is not a valid name for a Python identifier.

From the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers), for a name of an identifier, you can use characters of the English alphabet(a-z, A-Z), digits(0-9; not allowed as first character), underscore(_), and some restricted range of unicode characters (but this is very discouraged in practice!). '^' is not allowed in a name of an identifier.

So you have to change the name of your variable to fit the rule.